# A C function to find the first occurence of a substring

Tags: c, string, function, find, substring

HI there so I am trying to write a function that can find the first occurrence and that will return an integer that represents the index of the substring that is found. so for instance if the substring i was trying to find is 'dog' and the string is 'hotdog' it would return 4. if no substring is found, then it should return -1. also no using the function strstr. This is the function im working with

```
int findSubString(char original[], char toFind(){
```

Comment: Shouldn't the index in `"hotdog"` be `3`? Array indices in C start at `0`. This would be in tune with library functions such as `strcspn` which return an index into a string.

Comment: @user6913230  Are you from Canada Ontario?:)